# LLDB Terminal Output

Tags: macos, debugging, osx-mavericks, lldb

I'm using LLDB for the first time. I'm running MacOSX Mavericks. For some reason, I cannot get LLDB to print any lines of source code. Rather, the output appears to be assembly instruction set. How do I "fix" this so it shows the code instead?

**[c_src]>** lldb a.out

> Current executable set to 'a.out' (x86_64).
>   **(lldb)** breakpoint set -n main
>   Breakpoint 1: where = a.out main, address = 0x0000000100000d60
>   **(lldb)** run
>   Process 54010 launched: a.out (x86_64)
>   Process 54010 stopped
>   * thread #1: tid = 0x202742, 0x0000000100000d60 a.out`main, queue = com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
>      frame #0: 0x0000000100000d60 a.out`main
>   a.out`main:
>   -> 0x100000d60:  pushq  %rbp
>     0x100000d61:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
>     0x100000d64:  subq   $2032, %rsp
>     0x100000d6b:  movq   4766(%rip), %rax          ; (void *)0x00007fff72d37420: __stack_chk_guard

**(lldb)** s

> Process 54010 stopped
>   * thread #1: tid = 0x202742, 0x0000000100000d61 a.out`main + 1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = instruction step into
>
>       frame #0: 0x0000000100000d61 a.out`main + 1
>   a.out`main + 1:
>   -> 0x100000d61:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
>     0x100000d64:  subq   $2032, %rsp
>     0x100000d6b:  movq   4766(%rip), %rax          ; (void *)0x00007fff72d37420: __stack_chk_guard
>     0x100000d72:  movq   (%rax), %rax

I'm trying to get the "s" command to show where it has stepped to in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you haven't built your a.out with debug information.  For instance, if lldb had debug info for a.out, it would have printed the source line in reporting the breakpoint at main.

If you are building your a.out by hand, remember the -g flag.  If you are using Xcode, be sure to set the Debug Format to DWARF.

Comment: It works. I can't believe I forgot the -g on the command line.